# Difference between nodes and waypoints OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

What is the main difference between a node and a waypoint in OpenStreetMap? I know both represent a point on the map. Also what is the significance of node 0?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no entity type called "waypoint" in openstreetmap. Neither am I aware of any special significance of node 0. Where have you found these concepts?

Comment: waypoint has the same definition of a node. I am curious to know the difference between the two.

Comment: @TurePålsson When you query for nearest point using OSRM the result object is a collection of waypoint objects . Each way[point object has a property called         
 nodes [a b]   where a and b are node ids

Comment: Can you re-phrase those parts of your question, where you specifically refer to OSRM, rather than OSM in general?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like waypoint is something from OSRM.

In OpenStreetMap, a node is the fundamental object type  carrying geographic positions. Only node objects have position; other objects (ways and relations) refer to nodes.

I'm not familiar with OSRM, but a [waypoint seems to be what they call a point on a route](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.22.0/api/#waypoint-object).